# Provide local locations to user in Android

Tags: android, location

In Android, I'm trying trying to have the user enter a place they name, say Walmart, then my program will give them the closest X number that matches that name. I know Geocoder can do this with major or  specific locations, but I simply type in Walmart into it, it returns `null` which means it cannot find it.

Is there a way in Android, either using the Maps API or something else to have it perform and return the results for anything the user types in?

Comment: you typed "walmart near x" where x was your location right?

Comment: Yes. I tried Walmart near (zip), Walmart near (state), Walmart near (City) and none returned anything except null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you'll need to use the [Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/index#PlaceSearches) from Google or the like to accomplish this.
You'll need the user's GPS coordinates or use network location. This can be tricky as they are allowed to deny access to those services in the settings. So be aware of that.

GeoCoder isn't that great for that. It's better at resolving addresses from a location. It's not meant as a search tool for finding the closest Walmart. Notice that [getLocationName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) does not accept coordinates. "Walmart" to it would be very ambiguous the best it could do is return all walmart locations which probably won't happen.

Comment: I know "Walmart" would be ambigous, but I was hoping that it would return the nearest X results, where X is the limit you give to Geocoder when you call it. The Maps API looks like the best solution, thank you.